Best practise to typePolicies with Apollo
I want to have centralized client-only fields.
Example:
Server:
type Name {
  first: String
  last: String
}

type User  {
  name: Name
}

Client:
extend type User {
  fullName: String!
}


import { StrictTypedTypePolicies } from '@/__generated__/apollo-helpers'; // @graphql-codegen/apollo-helpers
import { Name } from '@/__generated__/graphql';

export const userTypePolicies: StrictTypedTypePolicies = {
  User: {
    fields: {
      fullName(_, { readField }) {
        const name = readField<Name>('name');

        return `${name?.first} ${name?.last}`.trim();
      },
    },
  },
};


user {
  id
  fullName @client
}

The problem: if I use for example a normal helper function to a fetched object like getFullName(user) then it's type-safe.
But when I query only fullName @client then I don't guarantee that this query also selects name { first, last } and my custom type policy would fail and the only thing I can do is a runtime error while checking for the existence of readField('name')
Any solutions to this problem?
update:
With the help of ChatGPT I'm trying to implement the following codegen plugin:
client schema
directive @depends(fragment: String) on FIELD_DEFINITION

fragment User_fullName on User {
  firstName
  lastName
}

extend type User {
  fullName: String! @depends(fragment: "User_fullName")
}

query:
  query ($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      id

      fullName @client

    }
  }

Type policy:
import { StrictTypedTypePolicies } from '@/__generated__/apollo-helpers';
import { User_fullNameFragmentDoc } from '@/__generated__/graphql';

export const userTypePolicies: StrictTypedTypePolicies = {
  User: {
    fields: {
      fullName(ref, { cache }) {
        const current = cache.readFragment({
          id: ref as string,
          fragment: User_fullNameFragmentDoc,
        });

        return `${current?.firstName} ${current?.lastName}`;
      },
    },
  },
};

Final generated with plugin query should look like:
query UserQuery ($id: ID!) {
  user(id: $id) {
    id

    fullName @client
    ...User_fullName
  }
}
fragment User_fullName on User {
  firstName
  lastName
}

How good does it look?
Update: that's a plugin, use it as a documentsTransform, works great https://gist.github.com/SPAHI4/a599015997d67789627fadb1f434454e

To ensure that the necessary server fields are always included when querying a client-only field, you can use a GraphQL fragment that includes both the server fields and the client-only field.To ensure that the necessary server fields are always included when querying a client-only field, you can use a GraphQL fragment that includes both the server fields and the client-only field.
Here’s how you can define a fragment:
fragment UserFullNameFields on User {
  name {
    first
    last
  }
  fullName @client
}

use it in your query:
query GetUser {
  user {
    id
    ...UserFullNameFields
  }
}

I hope this helps resolve the issue!
Fore more info:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/
Furthermore,to handle cases where some data might be missing, you can add validation in your Apollo Client type policies. This helps to manage situations where the required server fields are not available.

Thank you. Yes, I've come to the same decision.
One thing that because of fragment masking and readability do not include @client field into fragment, and request like ...__User_fullName fullName @client
But this doesn't look fancy

Thanks, I know it’s not the fancy, but it should get the job done. If you want to make it look better, let me know, and I’ll try to help out.

Thank you. I've updated the question with my thoughts
